# Fetching second row value from stored procedure in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as 
begin
   select t.TBarcode, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate from Transaction_tbl t where TBarcode=@carid
   declare @transid integer=null
   select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid
   select count(k.transactid) transid from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid
end
```

while executing stored procedure i am getting out put like this:

```
Tbarcode   paid status
1111         0    2

Transid
2
```

How I can fetch Transid value in vb.net?

I Fetched first row value like this:

```
 Dim cmdcarvalidation As New SqlCommand("carcallvalidation", con.connect)
 cmdcarvalidation.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
 cmdcarvalidation.Parameters.Add("@carid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = txtTicket.Text
 dr = cmdcarvalidation.ExecuteReader
 While dr.Read
    tbarcode=dr("Tbarcode")
    payd= dr("paid")
    status= dr("status")
 end while
```

Answer (score 0):

[SqlDataReader.NextResult Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

`NextResult` is used to move to the next result set when you have multiple result sets - by default the reader is positioned at the first result set.

So:

```
While dr.Read()
    tbarcode = dr("Tbarcode")
    payd = dr("paid")
    status = dr("status")
End While

dr.NextResult()

While dr.Read()
    transid = dr(0)
End While

dr.NextResult()

While dr.Read()
    transid_count = dr(transid)
End While
```

If you simply want the 1st and 3rd results from your stored proc (skipping the `SELECT @transid` result set), you'd omit the second `dr.Read()`:

```
While dr.Read()
    ' process first result set
End While

dr.NextResult()
dr.NextResult()

While dr.Read()
    ' process the third result set
End While
```